# Hosting a domain on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

Is there a step by step guide on how to host a new domain name on IIS 7.5? Configuring everything, email, FTP, IIS, etc ...

Thank you & regards
Bilal

Answer (score 2):

[Hosting Applications on IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/106/hosting-applications-on-iis-7/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Lots of information that makes things even worse :)

Comment: Configuring everything, email, FTP, IIS, etc .......that's what you wanted, As per your question this is the best link as per my understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of writing some step-by-step guides right now. They'll be available in a few months. In the meantime, I suggest you check out the following: [IIS 7 Installation and Deployment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692294%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Windows VPS or a Dedicated Server? 
I don't have step by step guide (lengthy work) for Configuring everything like IIS, mySQL, etc ... but the following link may be useful ... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972

For our clients, What we do is, we install WebsitePanel on their Dedicated Server / VPS server and then configure all other services like IIS, mySQL, SQL Server, etc ...

Basically, we deliver them ready to use web servers, where they can start hosting their websites immediately.

Just PM me and I will see what I can do for you to get you rolling ...