# Publish Web Site on IIS - Assign Name

Tags: asp.net, iis, browser, domain-name

I have deployed a asp.net developed site on my machine IIS. In order to access it I type "localhost" in my browser and it is accessible. How can I change the DN of my site i.e. I want to access site from Browser on any machine at my Local Network as "localhost/WallBoard". If I type WallBoard in Host name it doesn't run on Browser giving error.  Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hosting a domain on IIS 7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903677/hosting-a-domain-on-iis-7-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to give it a host name, and then set up that host name in your hosts file locally pointing to your IP address.

Comment: In this manner I will have to place hosts file on every machine that needs to access this on a Local Network. That way too laborious

Comment: This wasn't mentioned in the original post, you need to set it up in the DNS for the local network if you wish to access it elsewhere on the network.

Comment: Edit@ Done (y) Thank you

Comment: Localhost will always point to the local machine, what you are asking is not possible. As per my previous comment you will need to add the host and IP to the DNS for the network.

Comment: Just tried that - still not accessible. First I want to make this change to my machine then accessing from others can be managed as well.

Comment: Last comment at this is getting towards a chat, you probably need to open port 80 on the firewall on your machine.